# How to use VSMTP Volusion

Tags: volusion

Can any buddy tell me that how to use VSMTP to send email in volusion ?

they provided article http://support.volusion.com/article/vsmtp-key  for that but i am unable to make it work.

Actually, I want to use for Form. once user/visitor fill form and click on send button. Email will send along with details using VSMTP.

Volusion already providing custom form option but for that we must require to use CAPTCHA. That we dont want to use.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Its just a web service.  They have provided a reference implementation of using it with ASP.  Just download that ASP file and use it within an ASP files to send an email from your form.